# SwiftUIの画面遷移でUse of unresolved identifie

Tags: swift, swiftui

SwiftUIを使った画面遷移のテストをしていたところ、`NavigationLink`の`destionation`で遷移先を指定する時に`Use of unresolved identifie`のエラーがでます。
これは定義されてないものが呼び出された時に発生するエラーだそうですが他ファイルで定義した場合どうすれば良いのでしょうか？

[ContentView.swift]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: SubView()){
                    Text("GO!!!")
                }

            } .navigationBarTitle("Home")
        }
    }
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[SubView.swift]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SubView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("this is subview").font(.title).fontWeight(.bold).frame(width: 400, height: 100).border(Color.orange, width:4)
    }
}

struct SubView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SubView()
    }
}
```

エラー

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'SubView'
```

Comment: `SubView`と言う名前のデータ型を定義したファイルがプロジェクトに存在すれば、そのようなエラーは出ません。**(1)SubView.swift がプロジェクトに追加されていない(ファイルが存在しても、Target Membershipにチェックが入っていないとプロジェクトに追加したことにはならない)**、または、**(2)Xcodeが古いエラーを表示してしまっているだけ**、あたりの理由が考えられます。(1)の方はデフォルトで新規ファイルにはチェックが入るので(2)の方を先にチェックしてみるべきでしょう。クリーンビルド(Product > Clean Build Folder してから、Product > Build)は試してみましたか?

Comment: 今日改めてXcodeを起動して試してみたところエラーが消えたので、古いエラーを表示してしまっていたのだと思います。